# WriterT transforming a list monad - how do inner and outer monad work together?

Tags: haskell

In the *Beginning Haskell* book on page 181, there is an example of using `WriterT` to wrap a `List` monad. The code below computes paths in a graph. Note that this is a very trivial algorithm not taking loops into account).

```haskell
type Vertex = Int
type Edge = (Vertex, Vertex)

pathsWriterT :: [Edge] -> Vertex -> Vertex -> [[Vertex]]
pathsWriterT edges start end = execWriterT (pathsWriterT' edges start end)

pathsWriterT' :: [Edge] -> Vertex -> Vertex -> WriterT [Vertex] [] ()
pathsWriterT' edges start end =
  let e_paths = do (e_start, e_end) <- lift edges
                   guard $ e_start == start
                   tell [start]
                   pathsWriterT' edges e_end end
   in if start == end
      then tell [start] `mplus` e_paths
      else e_paths
```

In both `let` and `in` blocks of `pathsWriterT'` I'm *telling* the writer to add the current vertex to the path. But later in the `pathsWriterT` by *executing* the writer I'm getting the list of possible paths.

How the Writer combines all computed paths into the list of paths? How are different paths "stored" independently in a single computation represented by `WriterT`? (pardon my imperative language)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that a `Monad` in Haskell is a type `m :: * -> *` that supports two operations:

1. `return :: a -> m a`
2. `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

Although it is often useful to think about a sequence of actions in `do`-notation as a computation, when you're interested in what's going on under the hood, you should think about values of type `m a` and what happens to them when `return` and `(>>=)` are involved.

The monad in question is `WriterT [Vertex] []`. And this is how `WriterT` is defined:

```
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (a, w) }
```

Substitute `[Vertex]` for `w` and `[]` for `m`. We get this:

```
[(a, [Vertex])]
```

so it's a list of values of type `a`, each value has a list of vertices associated with it. Those types are *equivalent* modulo newtype wrapping/unwrapping. Now we need to understand how `return` and `(>>=)` work for this type.

`return` for `[]` creates a singleton list. So `return 'x' :: [Char]` is `['x']`. `return` for `WriterT` sets the accumulator to `mempty` and delegates the rest of the job to the `return` of the inner monad.

In our case, the accumulator has type `[Vertex]` and `mempty :: [Vertex]` is `[]`. This means that `return 'x' :: WriterT [Vertex] [] Char` is represented as `[('x', [])]` — the `'x'` character with an empty list of vertices. That's pretty straightforward: the `return` method of our monad creates a singleton list with no vertices associated with the only value in this list.

The tricky part is, of course, the `(>>=)` operator (pronounced "bind", in case you didn't know). For lists it has type `[a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]`. Its semantics are that the function `a -> [b]` will be applied to each element in `[a]`, and the resulting `[[b]]` will be concatenated.

`[a, b, c] >>= f` will become `f a ++ f b ++ f c`. A simple example to demonstrate:

```haskell
[10, 20, 30] >>= \a -> [a - 5, a + 5]
```

Can you figure out what the resulting list will be? (Run the example in GHCi, if not).

Nothing prevents you from using `(>>=)` within the function supplied to another `(>>=)`:

```haskell
[10, 20, 30] >>= \a ->
  [subtract 5, (+5)] >>= \f ->
    [f a]
```

Indeed, this is how the `do`-notation works. The above example is equivalent to:

```haskell
do
  a <- [10, 20, 30]
  f <- [subtract 5, (+5)]
  return (f a)
```

So it's like building a tree of values and then flattening it into a single list. Initial tree:

```
a <-               (10)-----------------(20)------------------(30)
                    |                     |                     |
                    |                     |                     |
                    v                     v                     v
f <-   (subtract 5)----(+5)  (subtract 5)----(+5)  (subtract 5)----(+5)
               |        |            |        |            |        |
               |        |            |        |            |        |
               v        v            v        v            v        v
             [f a]    [f a]        [f a]    [f a]        [f a]    [f a]
```

Step 1 (substitute `f`):

```
a <-       (10)-----------------(20)-------------------(30)
            |                     |                     |
            |                     |                     |
            v                     v                     v
    [subtract 5 a, a + 5]  [subtract 5 a, a + 5] [subtract 5 a, a + 5]
```

Step 2 (substitute `a`):

```
[subtract 5 10, 10 + 5, subtract 5 20, 20 + 5, subtract 5 30, 30 + 5]
```

And then, of course, it reduces to `[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]`.

Now, as you can remember, `WriterT` adds an accumulator to each of your values. So at each step of flattening the tree, it will use `mappend` to merge those accumulators.

Let's get back to your example, `pathWriterT'`. To ease the understanding, I will modify it a little bit to remove the handling of self-loops and to make binding units explicit:

```haskell
pathsWriterT' :: [Edge] -> Vertex -> Vertex -> WriterT [Vertex] [] ()
pathsWriterT' edges start end
  | start == end = tell [end]
  | otherwise    = do
    (e_start, e_end) <- lift edges
    () <- guard $ e_start == start
    () <- tell [start]
    pathsWriterT' edges e_end end
```

Consider an invocation of `pathsWriterT'` where

- `edges` = `[(1,2), (2,3), (2,4)]`
- `start` = `1`
- `end` = `4`

Once again, we can draw a tree, but it will be quite more complex, so let's do it line-by-line:

```haskell
{- Line 1 -} (e_start, e_end) <- lift edges
{- Line 2 -} () <- guard $ e_start == start
{- Line 3 -} () <- tell [start]
{- Line 4 -} pathsWriterT' edges e_end end
```

Line 1. The type of `edges` is `[Edge]`. When you apply `lift` from `MonadTrans` to them, it becomes `WriterT [Vertex] [] Edge`. Remember that under the hood this is simply `[(Edge, [Vertex])]`. The implementation of `lift` for `WriterT` is straightforward: set accumulator to `mempty` for each value. Thus now we have `lift edges` equal to:

```
[ ((1,2), []) ,
  ((2,3), []) ,
  ((2,4), []) ]
```

And our tree is:

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
```

For each of those `(e_start, e_end)` values, the following happens...

Line 2. The source vertex of an edge is bound to `e_start` and the target vertex is bound to `e_end`. `guard` expands to `return ()` when its argument is `True` and to `empty` when it's `False`. For lists, `return ()` is `[()]` and `empty` is `[]`. For our monad, we have the same but with accumulators: `return ()` is `[((), [])]` and `empty` is still `[]` (because there's no values to attach an accumulator to). Since we decided that `start` = `1`, the results of evaluating `guard` are:

- for `(1,2)`, `[((), [])]`
- for `(2,3)`, `[]`
- for `(2,4)`, `[]`

There are three results because we're working with *each* element. Let's add them to our tree:

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
```

As you see, I wrote `none` in place of children nodes for `(2,3)` and `(2,4)`. That's because `guard` didn't provide them with children nodes, it returned an empty list. And now we proceed...

Line 3. Now we use `tell` to expand the accumulator. `tell` returns the unit value, `()`, but with an accumulator attached to it. Since `start` equals to `1`, the accumulator will be `[1]`. So let's adjust our tree:

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
```

Line 4. Now we call `pathsWriterT' edges e_end end` to recursively continue building the tree! Cool. Inside this recursive invocation: we have:

- `edges` = old `edges`
- `start` = old `e_end` = `2`
- `end` = old `end` = `4`

We're back at line 1. Our tree now looks like this:

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
```

And line 2 again... only this time, it will leave us with different nodes (as `start` has changed)!

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
```

And line 3 again, now it will add `[2]` as accumulator.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])      ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
                                               |               |
                                               |               |
                                               v               v
()               <-                       ((), [2])       ((), [2])
```

At line 4 we recurse into `pathsWriterT'`.

- `edges` = old `edges`
- `start` = old `e_end` = `3`, `4`
- `end` = old `end` = `4`

Notice that I wrote both `3` and `4` as values of `e_end`. That's because recursion happens in both branches:

1. In branch `(2,3)` we will once again go create a child per edge.
2. In branch `(2,4)`, however, notice that `start == end` holds, bringing the end to recursion. We create a child `[((), [4])]` because that's the result of `tell [4]` for our monad.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
                                               |               |
                                               |               |
                                               v               v
()               <-                       ((), [2])       ((), [2])
                                               |               |
                           ____________________|____           v
                           |            |          |      [((), [4])]
                           v            v          v
(e_start, e_end) <- ((1,2), [])  ((2,3), [])  ((2,4), [])
```

At line 2, the guard won't let any new children to appear here, because there's no node to satisfy `e_start == 4`.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
                                               |               |
                                               |               |
                                               v               v
()               <-                       ((), [2])       ((), [2])
                                               |               |
                           ____________________|____           v
                           |            |          |      [((), [4])]
                           v            v          v
(e_start, e_end) <- ((1,2), [])  ((2,3), [])  ((2,4), [])
                           |            |          |
                           |            |          |
                          none         none       none
()               <-
```

Whew! Our tree is built. Now it's time to reduce it. I will decrease the depth of our tree by 1 at each reduction step, going bottom-up. At each reduction step I will replace the parent with the concatenated list of its children, and `mappend` the parent's accumulator to the accumulators of its children. Why this exact logic? Well, that's just how `(>>=)` is defined for our monad.

Notice that the leafs of our tree have type `[((), [Vertex])]` — that's the return type of `pathsWriterT'`. Remember that `none` stands for empty list `[]`, so it has this type as well. And inner nodes have type `(a, [Vertex])`, where `a` is the type of the bound variable (I've drawn variable bindings to the left of the tree).

Step 1.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
                                               |               |
                                               |               |
                                               v               v
()               <-                       ((), [2])       ((), [2])
                                               |               |
                           ____________________|____           v
                           |            |          |      [((), [4])]
                          none         none       none
```

Step 2.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
                                               |               |
                                               |               |
                                               v               v
()               <-                       ((), [2])       ((), [2])
                                               |               |
                                              none             v
                                                          [((), [4])]
```

Step 3.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none                v               v
()               <-                        ((), [])        ((), [])
                                               |               |
                                               |               |
                                              none             v
                                                         [((), [2,4])]
```

Step 4.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                             v                 v               v
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])      ((2,3), [])     ((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                           none               none             v
                                                         [((), [2,4])]
```

Step 5.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
()               <-      ((), [1])
                             |
                             |\_________________________________
                             |                 |               |
                           none               none             v
                                                         [((), [2,4])]
```

Step 6.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
()               <-      ((), [])
                             |
                             |
                             v
                       [((), [1,2,4])]
```

Step 7.

```
(e_start, e_end) <-    ((1,2), [])------((2,3), [])-----((2,4), [])
                             |                 |               |
                             |                 |               |
                             v                none            none
                       [((), [1,2,4])]
```

Step 8.

```
                       [((), [1,2,4])]
```

`execWriterT` will discard the values and leave only the accumulators, and now we're left with `[[1,2,4]]`, which means that there's only one path from `1` to `4`: `[1,2,4]`.

Exercise: do the same (with pen and paper) but for `edges` = `[(1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (3,4)]`. You should get `[[1,2,4], [1,3,4]]`.

Comment: In the list monad example, reduction part. Should the partial lists be `[subtract 5 a, a + 5]`?